# If $\text{Tor}^R_1(M,R/xR)=0$, then is $x$ necessarily $M$-regular?

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-functors, local-rings

Let $M$ be a finitely generated module over a Noetherian local ring $(R,\mathfrak m)$. Let $x\in \mathfrak m$ be such that $\text{Tor}^R_1(M,R/xR)=0.$ Then, is it true that $x$ is $M$-regular?

I can prove this under the extra hypothesis that $x$ is $R$-regular. Indeed, in that case we have the exact sequence $0\to R \xrightarrow{\cdot x} R \to R/xR\to 0$. Tensoring with $M$ we get

$$\text{Tor}^R_1(M,R/xR)\to M \xrightarrow{\cdot x} M \to M/xM\to 0$$ Now remembering $\text{Tor}^R_1(M,R/xR)=0$ we get the exact sequence $0\to M \xrightarrow{\cdot x} M \to M/xM\to 0$ which gives $x$ is $M$-regular.

However, I'm not sure what happens if we do not assume $x$ is $R$-regular. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true if $x$ is not assumed to be $R$-regular. Just take for $x$ any zero divisor and $M=R$ as in this case we always have $\operatorname{Tor}_1^R(M,R/xR)=0$. Alternatively take $x=0$ and $M$ any module.

Comment: Thanks ... is there any example where $M$ is not free?

Comment: @SnakeEyes Yes, $x=0$ and $M$ any module.

Answer (score 2):

Take $R=k[y]/(y^3)$, $x=y^2$ and $M=R$.

Now $Tor^R_1(M, R/xR)=0$ since M is free $R$-module.

But $x$ kills $y$ in $M$, so not $M$-regular.

Comment: Thanks ... is there any example where $M$ is not free?